# How do you copy sample code in the clipboard using click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT START*****

This is not a duplicate, my question is bit different than what you have referenced. here is my updated code and I see that I'm getting innerHTML when I do console.log but it does not copy, is that possible if you can have that in a jsFiddler?

html code:

```
 <div id="mydivid">
     $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { $(this).toggleClass('active'); });
 </div>
```

javascript code:

```
const copy = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('mydivid');
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute("name", "codetextarea");
    textarea.value = el.innerHTML;
    alert(el.innerHTML);
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    textarea.remove();
}
```

EDIT END*****

I'm trying to copy code from a code tag using JavaScript. It works, but it copies the text in one long line of text. I want it to copy with the exact format, for an example see this web site:
https://leetcode.com/articles/two-sum/#approach-1-brute-force

My question, how can I implement the same logic of `copy` code as in the above website?

here is my code:

```
copy: function(component,event,text) {
        // Create an hidden input
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
        // passed text into the input
        hiddenInput.setAttribute("value", text);
        // Append the hiddenInput input to the body
        document.body.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        // select the content
        hiddenInput.select();
        // Execute the copy command
        document.execCommand("copy");
        // Remove the input from the body after copy text
        document.body.removeChild(hiddenInput);
    }
```

Comment: The question is not accepting answers, so bear with me. Use a `textarea` element as the intermediate text copy element insead of an `input` to preserve line beaks as covered in the duplicate and here. Get the text to copy from the `<code id="mycode">` element alluded to in the question using  its `textContent` property, not `innerHTML`. Nesting the `code` tag inside a `pre` tag may help with its layout in HTML as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that an `input` cannot have any newline characters in it, so when you assign a string to its `.value`, and that string contains newline characters, they just disappear:

```js
input.value = 'foo\nbar';
console.log(input.value.includes('\n'));
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Use a textarea instead:

```
var hiddenInput = document.createElement("textarea");
```

Live snippet:

```js
const copy = function(text) {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  textarea.remove();
};

copy('foo bar');
console.log('done');
```

Live snippet copying the code from the comment:

```js
const copy = function(text) {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  textarea.remove();
};

copy(`<p><b>  var str = "Hello,World!"; </b></p> console.log("hello, there!"); <p><b>  $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { $(this).toggleClass('active'); }); </b></p>`);
console.log('done');
```

Another live snippet copying the `#mydivid` contents from the question:

```js
const copy = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('mydivid');
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textarea.setAttribute("name", "codetextarea");
  textarea.value = el.innerHTML;
  alert(el.innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  textarea.remove();
};

copy();
```

```html
<div id="mydivid">
  $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { $(this).toggleClass('active'); });
</div>
```

Comment: I replaced with `textarea` but does not copy to the clipboard

Comment: Works fine here - see live snippet in answer

Comment: i see with the code it's copying but how come I still see the `<p><b>` tag? please try this code code instead of `foo bar`

Comment: sample code to copy in the clipboard `<p><b> 
var str = "Hello,World!";
</b></p>
console.log("hello, there!");
<p><b> 
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
</b></p>`

Comment: `<p><b>` is part of the input string, so it'll be part of the copied text as well. If you don't want it to be part of the copied text, trim it off first? Or if you want to remove all HTML tags, use `DOMParser`, set an element's `innerHTML` to that text, then retrieve its `textContent` or `innerText`?

Comment: Thanks for being patience with me, I updated my question, please have a look at it.